# AJAX checkboxes in Views to change node values

Tags: views, ajax, forms

I have a use case in D7 where I need to make a listing of nodes in table format, and included in the fields are checkboxes that us AJAX to do  things like publish/unpublish a node and set other field values in the node.  I know I saw merlinofchaos mention somewhere that there is a way to do this in Views, but I haven't been able to find details on how.  I can do it easily enough by creating a table and manually filling the cells, but I would like to use Views if I can.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of documentation here, I ended up using a tableselect form element with a dropdown list of possible actions, in the way the core content admin form works (/admin/content).

Answer (score 0):

If you can "do it easily enough by creating a table and manually filling the cells," you can easily leverage Views' global custom text field along with rewriting to create whatever you need.  For example, create a view with whatever you want in the fields, just make sure one of them is nid. Then add a global custom text field after all of them and craft up whatever AJAX divs or spans or ids etc you need to call your functions, substituting the nid token where necessary in the markup.  Make sure that javascript is including on your page and you should be on your way.

Comment: OK, makes sense, but what I was thinking was to leverage the Form API #AJAX functionality, but since a table display in views isn't a form, that wouldn't be possible.  Would I just need to do something like do a .ajax() in the jQuery that calls a custom URL to change the node property?

Comment: I've used $.post() to do it as I am just now getting into ajaxifying things around here, but yes, basically you would set up a menu item that responds to whatever you wanted and returned success/fail information that your jQuery would then use to update the display.

Comment: The accepted answer here is for D6 and Forms, so doesn't apply exactly, but gives you the rough strokes of how everything works together:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670858/drupal-6-jquery-ajax-update-a-field